# Gnome focus mode

Tags: gnome-terminal, window, gnome-classic

I know this should be a silly question, but how do I change the window/terminal focus mode in Ubuntu 14.04.1 running GNOME Flashback (Compiz) [3.8.4]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install gnome tweak tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`), and there you have the option under "Windows" -> "Window focus mode"

Comment: if it works, please mark the answer as solved :-)

Comment: sorry, didn't know I could.